# How can I modify the colors of my theme for a single section of my site?

Tags: plugins, customization, themes

I have a client who wants a section within her current site to use different colors without affecting the other sections. I was thinking about using the plugin ''jonradio-multiple-theme' but is there a better way? This plugin hasn't been updated in two years and Im afraid it will eventually fail...

Answer (score 1):

Is it a custom written theme or did you buy it ? If your using a paid or some kind of pre wriiten theme. you can set child theme and can overwrite the css using template class or some kind of specific identifier.

Here how create a child theme,
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

This is the wordpress codex doc, I think no need to put codes here.